# How to automate browsing task in Tor via terminal?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, identity-change

I want to write some script which would automate task like entering a website and clicking on a certain button or filling a form and then reset the tor identity. Right now I can make a macro with iMacros, but it does not allow to reset identity during macro execution. How can I:

1. visit a certain url
2. do some task, e.g. click a button, which is identified by a tag in html
3. reset identity
4. wrap points 1-3 in a script to fully automate the task and possibly expand it (add a loop, print a text in terminal etc.)

I would like also limit the amount of downloaded data and browsers download images - will using Tor via terminal result in not downloading the images? If not, is there a way to download only text, so I will limit the traffic?

Comment: This is a general question about computing, the fact that you happen to have tor installed doesn't really make this a question about tor.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that this isn't strictly related to Tor, so should be closed. However, if you're after some sort of browser engine/driver, have a look at Marionette. (I can't immediately find any Tor-related tutorials, but Google is your friend.)

Comment: You guys are kinda dense (those who have previously answered this).  It's obvious he wants to drive Tor, not cURL or any other browser.   The reasons are obvious.  And yes it is specific to Tor.  As far as "Google is your friend" you're the top result on google, so :(

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se) + shell/Perl(depends on your task details)